# VC6 fopen mode parameter

Tags: fopen, visual-c++-6

I am trying to understand some legacy VC6 code, and see a call to `fopen` using a mode parameter of `"ra"`. What mode is this?

Answer (score 0):

By trial and error, I think it is the equivalent of "a+"